# how do I get all the four options with each question... like if i print question then how do i print all the four option of that particular question

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-quiz

```
from django.db import models


class Questions(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    choice1 = models.CharField("Choice1", max_length=50,default="option1")
    choice2 = models.CharField("Choice2", max_length=50,default="option2")
    choice3 = models.CharField("Choice3", max_length=50,default="option3")
    choice4 = models.CharField("Choice4", max_length=50,default="option4")
    choice = models.CharField("Choice", max_length=50,default="correct option")

def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

This is a modal for creating a question and its options.

now I want to show all four option with question.
when i write

```
Questions.objects.all()
```

then I only get a question only now how do i get options with the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models

answers = [
    ("answer_1", "Answer 1 Label"),
    ("answer_1", "Answer 2 Label"),
    # ...
]

class Questions(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=answers, default="answer_1")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```